# 0xc000000e after imaging windows 10 disk with dd

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, dd

So, trying to upgrade to SSD, I mounted my old drive and the new SSD to a second system and copied the disk using dd for windows. After putting everything back, using either drive (old or new), I get 0xc000000e (and 0xc000000f for a while) ('unable to access winload.efi'). Trying various suggestions (bcdedit, bootrec...) I noticed, on both drives, that anywhere inheritance is broken, I can't get to. So I see c:\Windows\WinSxS but nothing else under C:\Windows. I also don't see C:\Users, C:\Program Files, and so on. I don't see these folders under that second system, or booting to Windows 10 USB command prompt.

I think I need repair the file permissions then go back to the BCDedit and bootrec tools. Are there any tools (probably Linux) where I can edit the permissions on the files/folders I can't even see in Windows?

Thanks,

Comment: What commands did you use, exactly?

Comment: I don't remember Exactly, it was, I think, dd ifs=\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1 ofs=\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2 bs=<4k>
Where PHHYSICALDRIVE1 was the original and PHYSICALDRIVE2 was the SSD. I know the source and dest were correct. I don't remember the block size param but I believe it was 4k.

Comment: Did you run it from Windows installed on the old drive?

Comment: No, both the "old HDD" and the "New SSD" were mounted in a second system and copied using the OS of the second system.

Comment: I believe I copied the exact command, but won't be able to get it until after work tonight, if it makes a difference.

Comment: so, here is the exact call I made:dd if=\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1 of=\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2 bs=4096 --progress